# Gradle: How can I add some files to the root location of my jar file?

Tags: gradle, jar, build

I generate with gradle a jar file for my spring application and I want to add some resources to the root of the jar file.

Current result:

```
server.jar
|--org
|--META-INF
|--BOOT-INF
|----lib
|----classes
|------files from resources jar
|------other stuff
```

Desired result:

```
server.jar
|--files from resources jar <-- root location!!!
|--org
|--META-INF
|--BOOT-INF
|----lib
|----classes
|------other stuff
```

And here is my gradle jar task:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'chessgame-server'
    version = '1.0.0'
    from(zipTree("${rootProject.projectDir}/client/build/libs/chessgame-client-1.0.0.jar")) <-- resources
}
```

Anyone an idea how I can add files to the root location of my jar file?
Thanks